# How to move Linux on a USB stick to a hard drive partition?

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I was running Ubuntu on a USB stick for a while because my hard drive had failed. It had two partitions.

I recently installed a new hard drive and installed Windows on it. I created a new partition inside Windows that is larger than the USB stick.

My question is: how do I move Linux to this partition on the new hard disk so that I have a dual-boot system? I downloaded a program called EaseUS Todo Backup but it can only clone a hard disk onto a hard disk or a partition onto a partition. Ubuntu is installed on the whole USB stick and has two partitions of about equal size.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can clone the HDD, which is complicated http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8225-clone-your-ubuntu-installation-onto-a-new-hard-disk but if you tell we what exactly you want to save from your USB install, mabey we can find a way to do a new install and save the data

Comment: If you want to clone the drive I will simplify it for you, please  make another live USB/DVD so you have two (one to clone and a new one to boot) and boot to this, make sure all three devices are connected (two usb and one HDD) open a terminal and run sudo apt-get install ddrescue and when it finishes run lsblk and add all the output of this to the question.

Comment: @markkirby I don't understand. What will that do? I want the Linux install on a partition for dual booting. I don't want to use the whole hard drive.

Comment: You just want a new install in your partitrion ?

Comment: @markkirby Yes but I would rather clone the USB stick. I am a little nervous about trying to install to a new partition as I tried to do that in the past and it ended up inadvertently wiping out Windows even though I selected another partition.

Comment: The page I linked is how to clone your usb, also if you know Ubuntu well przemo's answer is the same thing,

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Ubuntu and moving home directory to your new system.

If you need to move it and it's a proper installation (not live version) then use

`dd bs=4M if=/dev/partition_on_pendrive of=/dev/partition_on_disk`

Then `chroot` into partition you've created and install grub. Don't forget about swap.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. You are talking about cloning a partition but the Linux install has two partitions and I don't know how they connect to each other.

Comment: Did you install system on pendrive or is it live distribution? If it's a live distro, then there is additional overlay partition and it becomes complicated. In that case I wouldn't recommend cloning, instead I would install new system and copy /etc /home. Use can always check /etc/fstab on pendrive (on running system) and mount overlay partition accordingly)

Comment: I installed a full system. It has two partitions, both around 7gb in size.

Comment: Could you run your computer from pendrive and paste the output of `mount` ?

Answer (score 0):

i used fsarchiver in SystemrescueCD(www.sysresccd.org).

Steps to backup and restore:

1. Boot with SystemrescueCD
2. type `fsarchiver probe` in terminal to see the devices
3. to save the Ubuntu 14.04(partition)  in `/dev/sdb1` as a `.fsa` file, type the below command in terminal

   $fsarchiver savefs -j2 -o /media/masha/Data/backup/backup/Ubuntu1404.fsa /dev/sdb1

NOTE: use -j2 (dual core) -j4 (quad) to speed up

1. to restore the Ubuntu 14.04(`fsa` file)  in `/dev/sda1`(OS partition), type the below command in terminal

   fsarchiver restfs /media/masha/Data/backup/backup/Ubuntu1404.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sda5
2. After restoring, open `Gparted`, select `/dev/sda5` and get new uuid.
3. mount `/dev/sda5` using `mount /mnt/ubuntu14 /dev/sda5` and update `ubuntu14/etc/fstab` with new id. And also update mtab file.
4. if required change host, hostname files.
5. then restart with ubuntu  and update grub using *Grub customiser*. verify uuid before updating

Answer (score 0):

I use Gparted and boot-repair on a live USB (in many system rescue iso).

Boot with this live USB.
Mount your external drive and your internal drive.

With Gparted :
Free space for the new primary partition (non logical) on your internal drive.
(size > size of the partition on the external drive).
Copy-paste the ext4 linux partition of your external drive on your free space created in the internal drive.
Wait ...
Adjust the size, add partition(s), add swap.

With boot-repair :
Update GRUB2.

Reboot (without USB stick and USB external drive).

You'll see grub menu, choose linux.
Test the settings of your linux programs.
Change in some programs /sdbX (or /sdaX or /sdcX) to /sdaY (Y = your / or /home partiton number).
You can also customize the GRUB2 menu with grub-customizer.

Et voilà.

JPol